# What can cause these strange AC current and power readings?

Tags: mains, voltage-monitor

We are attempting to monitor the power usage for a customer using a commercial digital power meter and Rogowski coils.  In one of the panels (3 phase 208/120) the current measurements are very unstable and the a small reverse power is being measured.  The installer is sure that the coils are not reversed.  Using a clamp on meter also shows unstable currents on the three legs.  The currents range for 4A to 14A on L1, 2A to 12A on L2, and 11A to 30A on L3, over the range of seconds.

The panel is powering a kitchen and cafe within a commercial building.  **Are there any types of loads that could cause such strange readings?**

The wiring in the location could also be an issue.  **Are there any wiring mistakes that could cause such strange readings?**

Comment: there are reports of smart meters with Rogowski coils measuring wrong values with non sinusoid currents like from switch-mode power supply's

Comment: Why did you choose R-coils and not CTs?

Comment: The coils were chosen for ease of installation.  They're working fine on 10 other panels.  It's just this one panel that's giving us problems.